# Tool for adding raster values to vector z axis

Tags: qgis-3, 3d-analyst

In ArcGIS, there is a tool called ["Interpolate Shape"](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/interpolate-shape.htm) which takes a vector layer and underneath a raster. Then it adds the raster grid values to the vectors z-coordinates.

Is there a tool in QGIS that does the same or sth. similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the vector type and what you want to do.

If you want to set Z value to line or points only. Use `Drape (set Z value from raster)`.

If you want points in polygon, I suggest to convert polygon to raster via `Rasterize (vector to raster)`, then you can convert the raster to points and after that use `Sample raster values` or `Drape` again.

IF you have line layer, use `Generate points (pixel centroids) along line`. And convert line to points, after that use again `Sample raster values` or `Drape`

If you have point layer, just use `Sample raster values` or `Drape`.